# How to make dynamically search query via GET request

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying publish some GET route in my application, that will handle both simple "GET ALL" query and filtered data query in my app using request.query.. There is more correct way then :

```
if (!req.query) {

  // Find query
  albumsHandler.album.find({}, function (err, albums) {
    if (!albums) return res.sendStatus(400);
    res.send(albums);

    if (mongoose.connection.readyState != CONSTS.MONGO_DISSCONECT_STATUS) {
      mongoose.connection.close();
    };

  });
}
else if (req.query.albumNumber) {

  // Find query
  albumsHandler.album.find({ albumNumber: req.query.albumNumber }, function (err, albums) {
    if (!albums) return res.sendStatus(400);
    res.send(albums);

    if (mongoose.connection.readyState != CONSTS.MONGO_DISSCONECT_STATUS) {
      mongoose.connection.close();
    };

  });

}
else if (req.query.albumNumber && req.query.artistNumber) {

  // Find query
  albumsHandler.album.find({ albumNumber: req.query.albumNumber, artistNum: req.query.artistNumber }, function (err, albums) {
    if (!albums) return res.sendStatus(400);
    res.send(albums);

    if (mongoose.connection.readyState != CONSTS.MONGO_DISSCONECT_STATUS) {
      mongoose.connection.close();
    };

  });

}
```

? because this way looks awful :| 
as you can see - I'm using NodeJS and mongoose.
Thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> because this way looks awful :| as you can see

you can do the following modifications to your code.So it will cleaner and efficient.

```
var album = require('album');
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.query) {
        // Find all
        album.getAll(req, res, next);
    }
    else if (req.query.albumNumber) {
        // Find query for albumNumber
        album.getAllNumbers(req, res, next);
    }
    else if (req.query.albumNumber && req.query.artistNumber) {
        // Find query for albumNumber and artistNumber
        album.getAlbumNumberAndArtists(req, res, next);
    }
});
```

you can split the logic.you can create a folder called controllers which talk to databases and create an album.js file which handles the data and sends the appropriate response. This makes your code reusable and prevent dry (don't repeat yourself).Now you have a cleaner API.Use

```
 res.json({
    albums:albums
 });
```

res.json eventually calls res.send

```
//inside album.js
//include mongoose
//include models

module.exports = {
  getAll : function(req, res, next){
  albumsHandler.album.find({}, function (err, albums) {
      if (!albums) return res.sendStatus(400);
      res.send(albums);

      if (mongoose.connection.readyState != CONSTS.MONGO_DISSCONECT_STATUS) {
          mongoose.connection.close();
      }
  });
  },

  getAllNumbers : function(req, res, next){
  albumsHandler.album.find({ albumNumber: req.query.albumNumber }, function (err, albums) {
      if (!albums) return res.sendStatus(400);
      res.send(albums);

      if (mongoose.connection.readyState != CONSTS.MONGO_DISSCONECT_STATUS) {
          mongoose.connection.close();
      }

  });
  },

  getAlbumNumberAndArtists : function(req, res, next){
    albumsHandler.album.find({ albumNumber: req.query.albumNumber, artistNum: req.query.artistNumber }, function (err, albums) {
        if (!albums) return res.sendStatus(400);
        res.send(albums);

        if (mongoose.connection.readyState != CONSTS.MONGO_DISSCONECT_STATUS) {
            mongoose.connection.close();
        }
    });
  }
};
```